# Authorization new user - keycloak

Tags: service, keycloak

I want to secure my user registration page with keycloak but couldn't think of any approaches while reading the docs. The best option for me:

- New user register, but his account is unavailable.
- When ADMIN accept this new account, user can log in.

Is it possible do it in keycloak ? Or any similar solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it. The easiest way is to give a default role to newly registred users. The default role would give only minimal privileges. Then ADMIN can promote the user to the more appropriate group or role.

Probably to "automate" or smoothen the second part of this flow you might need some flow customization. Cf. https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#required-action-walkthrough and related.

Another solution is to give to the default minimal role the possibility to request acceptation, or make the request automatically at first logging (eg. mail sent to ADMIN).

**EDIT**

Programmatically it is also possible to make calls to the Keycloak Admin API (through native Admin Client). For example, you can write some logic (and associated UI or whatever) that will assign or remove groups from a user.
See. [Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#admin-rest-api)